# php redirect script not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
require "assets/php/config.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$location = null;

if(isset($_GET['l']))
{

$location = retrieveAddress($_GET['l']);
}
if($location != null){

    header('Location: ' . $location);
}
else{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo 'Unknown link.';
}



public static function retrieveAddress($name)
    {
        $con = new PDO(Config::$host,
                  Config::$user,
                  Config::$password);
        if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $sql = $con->prepare('SELECT address FROM links WHERE name = ?');
        $sql->execute($name);
        $location = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $con = null;

        return $location;

    }
```

This script should allow me to go to my database where I save links and then redirect to that location, made it while working on a simple url shortener, I can easily add links so the database configuration works, however when I try to retrieve here nothing appears. I also tried to use error_reporting(E_ALL); but I still get nothing. Anyone got any idea, see anything wrong I fail to see?(I m sure there is something wrong but I can't notice

*Edit: I reach the file via link, no ajax is used. I removed all the text echos and I don t know how to check the value of the $location to see if I'm getting the proper value without using echo, I also edited the mysql to grab only the address, I was also getting the name, which was another mistake, but I seem to have one more somewhere.

Comment: Are you going to the url via link or ajax?

Comment: `if(location != null)` it's a typo ? Edit: May by helpful [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/3361444)

Comment: It should be if($location != null)

Comment: yes, typo, fixed, thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget my comment, i just saw you're sending output:

```
echo "before all";
```

before sending your headers. **Thats a big no-no**. You never send output before redirecting and generally never send headers after output. That includes `whitespace` as well.

Additionally, the `$location` is remaining `NULL` through all the script since you're changing it from `retrieveAddress`, yet since your variable is a global you either need to declare it as `global $location` inside function or access it as `$GLOBALS["location"]`

It would be easier if you just returned the $location from function also.

**UPDATE**

Apparently, the error was using `public static` outside of a class

```
public static function retrieveAddress($name)
    {
```

The result was that somehow *server got confused without returning any error or output*. The only clue we got *(me and OP)* was that mysterious message through firebug `Reload the page to get source for..`. One can find more info about this message **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486165/what-can-cause-a-persistent-reload-the-page-to-get-source-for-error-in-firebug)**.

So, in case anyone get funny responses from his server, without *errors*, better check for cases like the above.

Comment: I tried to both access it as $GLOBALS, declare it and return the $location from the function but still no response. Is there any way to make it give me a response?

Comment: Did you made the changes like removing all the text output? If yet, please update the question to know. Are you sure you're getting the correct `$location` after the functin's call? What do you mean response? How actually do you reach the file? link or ajax?

Comment: updated now together with all that you asked me but to summarize (I use a link, I'm installing Webug now to debug the php and see if the address is correct.

Comment: I don't see any other error except instead `$location` you need to access it with `$location[0]["address"]`

Comment: I can't think of any except that `error_reporting(E_ALL);` is giving some error (etc. output), which is highly unlikely since you're only including just a file before that (if that file doesnt exist for example it will give an error). The other thing i can think is some brilliantly hidden _whitespace_ before redirection, which is output. If you're not redirecting at all, what is the response after all, what is the server output?

Comment: Additionally, you want to exit the script by using `return;` or `exit;` _after_ the redirection.

Comment: well, what can I say I've done all that and looking at firebug I get no response from the request. Not sure about the procedure on linking somebody, but in case you wish to take a look, in the mean time I'll see if I can find a different way to get the link from my db. http://surl.bluebit.nu/index.php?l=34e5724 (and yes, I checked the parameter does exist in my db and it should return an address)

Comment: I figured it out, somehow, removing the keywords public static from the function fixed it, it works perfectly now. I however have no idea why, if you know, could you say as an answer, so I could validate it in case anyone else has this?

Comment: I absolutely have no idea why do you got that error, though i ran your site against my firebug + NET and got the `Reload the page to get source for..` where your HTML should be. Check **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486165/what-can-cause-a-persistent-reload-the-page-to-get-source-for-error-in-firebug)** for this. Glad you solve it :)

Comment: Yeah I had the same thing, I ll just put you as an answer, I hope people will scroll down in the mess of comments, thanks again.

Comment: I got it, static can only be accessed via a class, I was not using one. Documentation huzzah! Can you maybe edit your answer with that? It was the main fix.

Comment: added some extra info, thanx :) although very weird case. The question in link also doesn't bring any stunning solution to it,  though it presents some solutions to search furthermore.